# Background color and element height not always applied on page load

Tags: css, jquery-isotope, pageload

I was wondering if someone could give me some insight as to why the boxes on this page 
http://www.dreamhomevacationrentals.com/dream-homes/#
load sometimes without the white background and without their full height. Again... it only does this like... randomly.

Comment: Try removing the height from div.details.  This should at least allow the the white to wrap around the entire .accommodation_item.

Comment: Okay Marty, it seems as though that was the fix. Thanx a lot!